# Laravel problems with MCrypt

Tags: php, laravel, mcrypt

I'm trying to install all the package's of a Laravel project on a Virtual Machine. I've installed everything but during the composer install action show me the error MCrypt PHP Exstension Required.

But.. Mcrypt is installed! I've also do this actions:

```
locate mcrypt.ini 
locate mcrypt.so
```

and writed in mcrypt.ini the mcrypt.so php5 path.
so what contain now the mcrypt.ini file? just this text:

exstension=/usr/lib/20131226/mcrypt.so

also used: `php5enmod mcrypt` and `service apache2 restart` without any results..

Comment: If you create a script with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it, does it actually report mcrypt as being installed?

Comment: also check if your apache is using the same PHP version as your CLI

Comment: And restart php5-fpm just in case.

Comment: php5-fpm restarted, nothing change and also the php version is just one on this machine...

Comment: On Ubuntu apache and the cli have separate configurations. `php -i` can show different results to `<?php phpinfo();`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enabled your mcrypt extension?

Try with this command, it will tell you all the php extensions you have installed and wich one of them is active and wich one is not

`dpkg --get-selections | grep php`

If mcrypt is not enabled then try again to enable it with

`sudo php5enmod mcrypt`

Comment: Yes, I have installed Mcrypt... dpkg --get-selections return me
php5-mcrypt install
and yes i've also activated the mcrypt exstension using php5enmod..